# Copying file from folder 1 to folder 2 in terminal

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I am trying to move a text file from folder 1 to folder 2 via terminal. I'm doing this for a school project to show what actually happens when you copy paste.

I'm doing

```
cp/home/rits/desktop/folder1
cp/home/rits/desktop/folder2
```

and I get

```
rits@W:~$ cp/home/rits/desktop/folder1
bash: cp/home/rits/desktop/folder1: No such file or directory
tits@W:~$
```

If you guys can help me out or have any other commands to show how to do basic things like formatting a USB, deleting a file, making a new folder, copying and pasting, moving files via terminal please comment.

Comment: You may find this [cheatsheet](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9030259/Linux_Command_Line_Cheat_Sheet?pageNumber=1) useful, which lists and gives explanations of some of the most common commands.

Comment: Any command in bash require minimum one space between its name and its arguments. `cp` is not an exception from the rule. Please see `man cp`.

Answer (score 15):

Spot the difference:

```
cp /home/rits/Desktop/folder1/name_of_textfile /home/rits/Desktop/folder2/
```

- a space after `cp`
- desktop will be with a D, not a d
- after that are 2 arguments: filename and destination
- if you want to copy directories you need -R as an option after `cp`.

Comment: what if the folder name has a space in it? do i have to use an escape character?

Comment: Easier: use " (`cp "/test /a" "/test /b"`)

Answer (score 4):

You're using `cp` the incorrect way, and possibly your desktop folder is called `Desktop` (but in fact I am on a national language version, so I cannot be sure).

Let's assume that you have these 2 folders:

1. /home/rits/Desktop/folder1
2. /home/rits/Desktop/folder2

Also assume that `folder1` contains the file: `text.txt`. Now if you'd like to copy `text.txt` from `folder1` to `folder2`, you'd go:

```
cp /home/rits/Desktop/folder1/text.txt /home/rits/Desktop/folder2
```

To learn more about commands, either read the manual page of that command by typing `man command_name` or you can search the internet, and find a vast amount of beginner information like:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources

Comment: Location for folder1 is /home/rits/Desktop

Comment: Unix paths are case sensitive, so your commands must follow suit. Besides the syntax issues, it is just one other reason when the `No such file or directory` error message appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAC book, you are suppose to use following command

> cp -R "File/Path/abc.txt" "Destination/Folder/Path"